# Is it possible to select pictures only camera not storage in web app?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing some mobile web app which consists of html5, javascript and css.

Now I want to implement image upload function which accepts only their camera not their file storage.

Generally, `input type="file"` element accepts both files from their file storage and their camera app, or only their storage.

Now I want to restrict to select file image which has already saved.
Accepts only picture which has just taken their camera now.

Is it possible this in mobile web app using by html/JS
It is also ok not to use `input type="file"` tag, if there are good solution, I appreciate to share to me.

Thanks in advance.

```
  <input type="file" multiple="true" accept="image/*" style="" class="" >
```

Comment: A file is a file where ever it's stored, of course you can try to extract meta-information from the image and see when it's taken. But it sounds like you want to have native-application on android/ios which has a "take a picture" -functionality.

Comment: Yes, actually waht I want to do is distinguish whether this is 
picture has just taken or not.
That's same as native-application's 'take picture' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `capture="camera"` attribute and see if this is what you want.

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Note that the files selecting is still allowed on desktop browsers.

Comment: I have confirmed I can restrict from only camera in mobile browser.
Still I need to consider to prevent to upload picture 
form desctop application, but this advice is very useful for me. thank you.